# In TSQL, how to calculate time duration across 2 tables (login & logout logs)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I need to calculate time duration from 2 tables (1 login log & 1 logout log), each recording a datetime of the action and the accountID associated with it. The aim to see how long each account has been logged in between corresponding login & logout. The table schema is as below (since this is my first posting, apologize if the format is wrong.)

**UserLogInLog_201307**

-- DATETIME, datetime, not null

-- AccountID, int, not null

**UserLogOutLog_201307**

-- DATETIME, datetime, not null

-- AccountID, int, not null

Let's say the time period is 2013-07-17 to 2013-07-23.

I know I should use DATEDIFF to calculate, but the hard part is to pair each login and logout in the corresponding order, and to avoid the mess caused by split-day logins or logouts (i.e. if an account logged in 2013-07-12 & logged out 2013-07-13).

My initial solution is to use partition by AccountID & ranking by DATETIME as "anchor" for each pair, then I realized it was wrong due to the split-day mess.

Also I only have read-only access to the database, so I cannot create new tables / functions, etc.

Can someone give me an solution? Thank you very much in advance.

Here's my initial code (incorrect) for your reference:

```
-- RANK LOGOUT LOG BY LOGIN TIME
WITH cteLOGIN AS
(
    SELECT AccountID
          ,[DATETIME] AS [LOGIN]
          ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY [DATETIME] ASC) AS [xRANK]
        FROM [GameLog].[dbo].[UserLogInLog_201307]
        WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN '2013-07-17' AND '2013-07-23'
)

-- RANK LOGOUT LOG BY LOGOUT TIME
,cteLOGOUT AS
(
    SELECT AccountID
          ,[DATETIME] AS [LOGOUT]
          ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY [DATETIME] ASC) AS [xRANK]
        FROM [GameLog].[dbo].[UserLogOutLog_201307]
        WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN '2013-07-17' AND '2013-07-23'
)

-- COMBINE LOGIN & LOGOUT; MATCH RECORDS BY RANK #      
SELECT A.AccountID
      ,AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,A.LOGIN,B.LOGOUT)) AS AVG_TIME_DURATION
    FROM cteLOGIN A JOIN cteLOGOUT B ON A.AccountID = B.AccountID
    WHERE A.xRANK = B.xRANK
      AND A.LOGIN < B.LOGOUT
    GROUP BY A.AccountID
```

Comment: I wonder if AccountID is unique on both tables meaning let's say in your login we have `Account Number 101` and there is no other `Account Number 101` in the login table. And the same goes for log out table.

Comment: Hi @Edper, thanks for checking out. The AccountID isn't unique - whenever the account logs in or out, it leaves an entry, so there're multiple repetitions for each account on each log.

Comment: Could you provide some SQL to populate those two tables in such a way that we can see how your final query is incorrect? You mention "split-day logins or logouts", but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @Anssssss I wish I could... the problem is that I'm operating SQL on a security PC with no internet or USB, so I can't transfer any sample data. To illustrate, account A logged in and out 4 times within time range, so there are 4 pairs; but Account B may have logged in 2013-07-16, then logged out 2013-07-17, and then logged in & out 4 times, so account B has 4 logins within range but 5 logouts.

Comment: @Anssssss "split-day logins or logouts" means that the login for an Account is on another table while logout is on other table also hence the "split".

Comment: @RZY So in that situation where Account B logged in 4 times within the range and logged out 5 times, what would you like the query to do? Should it just ignore the earliest logout since that occurred before the first login within that time range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach here is to use a correlated subquery.

```
select ul.*, datediff(minute, datetime, logoutTime) as duration
from (select ulil.*,
             (select top 1 ulol.datetime
              from UserLogOutLog_201307 ulol
              where ulil.AccountId = ulol.AccountId and
                    ulol.datetime > ulil.datetime
             ) as logoutTime
      from UserLogInLog_201307 ulil
     ) ul;
```

You can then filter on the login date time.

Comment: Hi @Gorden thanks for the solution. Just ran this and the results seemed correct (I'm not sure because I'm not quite familiar with correlated subquery). Could you please explain to me how each part works? I'd appreciate it very much!

Comment: @RZY the query is pulling every entry from the login table, and bringing back the first entry in the logout table that corresponds to that user where the logout date is greater than the login date.

Comment: @MathewCollins Ah.. now it makes sense to me. Thanks a lot for the explanation:)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to combine the tables (don't worry, I won't ask you to change the schema). Here is a query which can produce a view of the tables where there are separate start and end times:

```
;WITH Unioned as
(
    select [AccountID] id, [DATETIME] dt, 'in' thing from UserLogInLog_201307
    union 
    select [AccountID] id, [DATETIME] dt, 'out' thing from UserLogOutLog_201307
)
,Combined as
(
    select id, dt StartDt, LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt)  EndDt, thing
    from Unioned
)
SELECT * from Combined 
WHERE 1=1
AND thing = 'in' AND EndDt IS NOT NULL /*only use rows where the current action is 'login' and there is a corresponding logout time*/
AND StartDt >= '2013-01-01 00:15' and EndDt <= '2013-01-03'
```

Now you should be able to use that do do your grouping by AccountID and taking the average datediff.

Comment: thanks for this solution. I understand the idea is to use LEAD() for ordering, but for some reason my SSMS (SQL Sever 2012) doesn't recognize it as built-in function:( Also, could you explain what `WHERE 1=1` does? Thanks!

Comment: You can ignore it, the WHERE 1=1 is just to make the conditions look a little nicer. Since 1=1 is always true, it becomes "WHERE true and x and y..." which logically is "WHERE x and y ...". I do that so I can comment out any line of the condition and the query still works when I'm testing it out. Regarding LEAD(), your SSMS client might be 2012, but the server you're connecting to is probably older (Select @@version).

Comment: Thanks @Anssssss for the explanation. And you're right, the server version is still 2008.